# How can I update a mongoid document's schema and remove "stale" fields from the old schema?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, schema

I'm trying to figure out how, using Mongoid, I can update my document schema and have any old fields no longer in the schema be automatically purged.

For example, let's say I have something like:

```
class Car
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :kind,  type: String
  field :model, type: String
end
```

And I do:

```
Car.create(kind: "Toyota", model: "Sequoia")
```

In the DB it looks like:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "55df818533aa6848de000000"
  },
  "kind": "Toyota",
  "model": "Sequoia"
}
```

I then later, in a separate session, redefine car as follows:

```
class Car
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :make,  type: String
  field :model, type: String
end
```

And I grab the existing record (there's only one for now):

```
car = Car.first
```

And update it:

```
car.make = "Honda"
car.model = "Accord"
car.save
```

If I then go look in the DB I have:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "55df818533aa6848de000000"
  },
  "kind": "Toyota",
  "model": "Accord",
  "make": "Honda"
}
```

In other words, even though my "schema" changed to be only "make" and "model", the attribute "kind" stayed in the document.

Is there a way to tell Mongoid "save and clear out unreferenced fields/objects"?

I'm not really sure what this is called, otherwise I'd probably find an answer to it... something about removing orphaned field definitions?

I welcome any help. Thanks!

---

Note: Mongoid "hides" this because when I go access the document based on the latest definition of Car, it only returns the relevant fields:

```
Car.last.inspect
"#<Car _id: 55df818533aa6848de000000, make: \"Honda\", model: \"Accord\">"
```

However, the "kind" field is still there in the DB. And in fact, if I redefine my schema again, to be something like:

```
class Car
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :kind,  type: String
  field :make,  type: String
  field :model, type: String
end
```

And go get the data record, it still has the "kind" field's data:

```
Car.last.inspect
"#<Car _id: 55df818533aa6848de000000, kind: \"Toyota\", make: \"Honda\", model: \"Accord\">"
```

I'm guessing this is intentional, but in my case, I'd rather have an option to explicitly clear out "stale" or "orphaned" fields.

Comment: You can remove them by hand with things like `Car.collection.find.update_all(:$unset => { :kind => true })`. But you'll need to track the schema changes yourself and have a migration system (which IMO you still need with MongoDB anyway).

Comment: I am hoping that there's something that will "auto-remove" them when the schema changes... i.e. when I update the Car object in the DB, with a new Car schema, it could clear the old attributes out. Maybe that's just not possible, though.

Comment: Nope, nothing like that. Schemas in MongoDB are really just loose suggestions (i.e. you can have documents with wildly different structures in one collection) so there's no safe way to automatically do what you want, you have to do it yourself.